# MS Access table: Populating one column based on others with SWITCH

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am working with two(2) tables in my MS Access database.  ChangeCodes and Items.  ChangeCodes has the following columns (Prefix, Suffix, and Description).

Here are sample rows:

```
Prefix  Suffix  Description
BE  2178    Business Enhancement
DP  1033    Development Problem
PE  2137    Performance Enhancement
PP  1687    Production Problem
TC  1001    Temporary Change
TE  1003    Technical Enhancement
WA  1005    Work Around
```

Items has the following columns (Item_ID, Item_Name, Entered_Date, Defect_Num,  Mod_Num, User_Entered, Code_Flag, Complete_Flag)

Here are sample rows:

```
BE0999  Fee Increment Stuffer   8/9/2001        NW5639  nakiris Yes Yes 
PE1084  Regionalizing RA99Z5UT  5/27/2008       NW7128  LUCKMAB Yes No  
PE1480  Resiliency task 300     2/22/2013       NW7768  SOUNDM2 No  No  
PP1092  Bad check               11/3/2003       NW6828  sangis1 No  No  
PP1093  To Avoid contention     11/7/2003       NW6829  narass1 No  No  
PP1094  Change to ensure ZERO   11/12/2003      NW6830  paletic No  No
```

As you can see Item_ID is a combination of the ChangeCodes.Preix and a 4 digit Suffix.  I wish to populate the Suffix of each row of the ChangeCodes table with the MAX value of the corresponding Item_ID in the Items table.  Is this SQL that will do this?  I have tried the following but the syntax is not correct.

```
SELECT 
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "BE", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'BE*';),   
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "DP", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'DP*';),
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "PE", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'PE*';),
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "PP", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'PP*';),
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "TC", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'TC*';),
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "TE", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'TE*';),
IIf([ChangeCodes.Prefix] = "WA", SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
        FROM Items
        WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'WA*';)
As Suffix 
FROM ChangeCodes;
```

Any idea how to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this well you have your table Items Id with some values and you want to populate changecodes based on your items table.

On your query you have Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4). Max only works with numbers and Item_ID is a string "BE0999".

You can try changing that expression for Max(CDec(Mid(Items.Item_ID),3,4)) or  Max(CInt(Mid(Items.Item_ID),3,4)).

The mid function will get you this part of the code "0999", however it is still a string you need to convert it to number before you use Max using CInt or CDec.

Not sure if it will work but worth the try.

Comment: Also notice that you start counting from 0 so this may be more appropriate Max(CInt(Mid(Items.Item_ID),2,4)) or Max(CDec(Mid(Items.Item_ID),2,4)).

Comment: None of the columns are defined as numbers.  Most are Short Text.  The inner SELECT seems to work independently of the SWITCH (case).    SELECT Mid(Max(Items.Item_ID),3,4) AS Expr1
FROM Items WHERE Items.Item_ID LIKE 'TC*'; returns four(4) digits that are the highest in that prefix group - which is what I want.